# $ex \leq e^x$ inequality using derivatives

Tags: calculus

So I was going through a sum for

Prove $ex \leq e^x$ , $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} $

I took $g(x) = e^x - ex$

Then $g'(x)= e^x - e$

I understood the case when $x>1$ function is strictly increasing i.e $g'(x) >0$ then $e^x>ex$ but what about when $x \leq 1$

Comment: Then the function is decreasing.  That's all you need.  Think about it for a moment.

Comment: Just re-wording what @saulspatz says: what does it mean for a function to have only one minima or maxima? Write it as inequality

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still getting a bit confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is easy to see $x=1$ is the absolute minimum, that is, $ f(1)\leq f(x)$  for all $x\in R$ so that $0\leq ex-e^x$.Thus $ex\leq e^x$ for all $x\in R.$

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$g(x)=e^x-ex \implies g'(x)=e^x-e=0\quad x=1$$

moreover $g''(x)=e^x > 0$, therefore $x=1$ is a point of minimum for $g(x)$.